# loopj infinite loop when host not found

Tags: android, loopj

I am trying to make use of loopj's Async HTTP library, but I encountered quite critical problem. When I am making a request to a host that does not exist it goes into infinite loop.

I tried debugging the code, but I didn't find much:

1. `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run()` runs and calls `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries()`
2. Then inside `makeRequestWithRetries()` `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest()` is called which throws `ConnectTimeoutException` that looks like it is being caught by `IOException` catch and `com.loopj.android.http.RetryHandler.retryRequest(IOException, int, HttpContext)` is called.
3. Then I app is not caught in any previous breakpoints, not even `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(Message)` and no message is fired, it just gets stuck.

However I am able to cancel this request with `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.cancelRequests(Context, boolean)`.

I have te newest possible code, because I got it yesterday from github and build myself.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue and this must be a major use/error case for everyone using the library..

Comment: Unfortunately not. I gave this up for now because of the deadlines. I will have to come back this later.

Comment: The latest version of the library has fixed this issue.. including the connection timeout now working properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned this in a comment, but I was having the same issue, and can confirm that the latest version of the library fixes this issue.

See this pull request: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/commit/87a615c3b86c3e33bd885435f98ab33483f874e9